# How to group items in a list with the same max date and filter them

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, ienumerable

I have `List<TakenBMI>` with these 4 columns and data:

```
TakenDate     UerID   TakenItem   TakenValue
Aug-10-2014     34     Weight       140
Aug-10-2014     34     Height       5.5
Mar-15-2015     34     Weight       141
Mar-15-2015     34     Height       5.5
```

I want to group them in separate lists based on the TakenDate and find out which list I should use that has details with the latest taken date.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var q = from n in TakenBMI 
        group n by n.TakenDate into g 
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.TakenDate )
                .FirstOrDefault(); 

var m = from n in TakenBMI 
        group n by n.TakenDate into g 
        select new { TakenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(q) };
```

Also, if anyone can suggest after getting the list with the max date one, how do I get to the 2nd latest date ones if possible? Thank you to everyone who replied

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I suggest you look at [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Also, is TakenDate a DateTime?

Comment: Yes, TakenDate is a Datetime.  I have tried this:

Comment: var q = from n in TakenBMI
    group n by n.TakenDate into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.TakenDate ).FirstOrDefault();



    var m = from n in TakenBMI
    group n by n.TakenDate into g
    select new { TakenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(q) };

Comment: can you add what are you receiving in m, so we don't have to run that by ourselves???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach by finding the latest date:

```
var latestDate = items.Select(i => i.TakenDate).Max();
```

Then by filtering items with that date:

```
var itemsWithLatestDate = items.Where(i => i.TakenDate == latestDate).ToList();
```

If you require all of them grouped in date order, then:

```
var itemsByDate = items.GroupBy(i => i.TakenDate).OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```

The latest date group would be the last of those groups:

```
var itemsWithLatestDate = itemsByDate.Last();
```

Comment: I was thinking it should be something similar to finding the max date first, will try this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a dictionary

```css
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TakenBMI> data = new List<TakenBMI>() {
               new TakenBMI() {TakenDate = DateTime.Parse("Aug-10-2014"), UerID = 34,  TakenItem = "Weight", TakenValue = 140},
               new TakenBMI() {TakenDate = DateTime.Parse("Aug-10-2014"), UerID = 34,  TakenItem = "Height", TakenValue = 5.5},
               new TakenBMI() {TakenDate = DateTime.Parse("Aug-15-2014"), UerID = 34,  TakenItem = "Weight", TakenValue = 141},
               new TakenBMI() {TakenDate = DateTime.Parse("Aug-15-2014"), UerID = 34,  TakenItem = "Height", TakenValue = 5.5},
            };

            Dictionary<DateTime, List<TakenBMI>> dict = data.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.TakenDate, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

        }
    }
    public class TakenBMI
    {
        public DateTime TakenDate {get;set;}
        public int UerID {get;set;}
        public string TakenItem {get;set;}
        public double TakenValue {get;set;} 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to group them in separate lists based on the TakenDate

You can *group by* `TakenDate` using `GroupBy()` LINQ query operator and enumerate over the result as follows:

```
var groups = TakenBMIList.GroupBy(x => x.TakenDate);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TakenDate: {0}", group.Key);

    List<TakenBMI> list = group.ToList(); //List of TakenBMI with current TakenDate
}
```

> find out which list I should use that has details with the latest
>   taken date

You can find element**s** with *latest (max)* `TakenDate` as follows:

```
var latestTakenBMIs = TakenBMIList.Where(x => x.TakenDate == TakenBMIList.Max(y => y.TakenDate)).ToList();
```